# When can isLocalStorageAvailable() return false on Android

Tags: android, libgdx

According to [this](http://www.badlogicgames.com/wordpress/?p=2305) Badlogic Games post about Android local files:

> The local storage is always available, which is not true for external
>   storage.

I'm a bit sceptic about this.
I know that my app needs the permission to the local storage (internal in Android nomenclature), but I suspect that there may be other cases when isLocalStorageAvailable() returns false on Android. Unfortunately I lack knowledge on Android architecture.

Could someone explain when may it happen (apart from the missing permission) and how much do I need to worry about that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could've read [THIS link](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html) instead of a blogpost, but...

If your app has the permission for local storage, and the user accepts it - thats about it. The only thing you need to worry about it not wasting all of the user's (free) space.

Comment: Thanks, I should have mentioned that I know about permissions. I'll add it to my question.